# C# : NotifyIcon is not raising event when the ballon tip is in action center on windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, win32gui

Program.cs code -

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

For Form1

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var displayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        displayIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
        displayIcon.BalloonTipText = "test";
        displayIcon.Visible = true;
        displayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(3000);

        displayIcon.Click += DisplayIcon_Click;
        displayIcon.BalloonTipClicked += DisplayIcon_BalloonTipClicked;
    }

    private void DisplayIcon_BalloonTipClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //   throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void DisplayIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

The event DisplayIcon_BalloonTipClicked is raised when ballon notification appears on desktop for 3 seconds. But if the notification goes to the action center, even if the app is running, the event is not raised. Please suggest what is wrong here.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue on v1803 (as reported by `winver.exe`).

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue. I'm guessing that there's an action center event that I need to tie into but trying to figure out how. Did you ever resolve this?